# Grab facebook user ID and pass from iOS app to MySQL?

Tags: php, iphone, mysql, xcode

I have developed an app that successfully uses Facebook Connect to allow the user to log in.  Once logged in, the user has the ability to upload photos to my server.  The URL link to these photos/images gets stored in MySQL.  I need to link their facebook user ID to their photos in my database.  So my questions are:

How do I grab the user ID in Xcode?
How do I then pass it thru to MySQL?
What does all of this code look like?

In response to Joel's answer, how would I add the Facebook credentials to NSUserDefaults?  I know how to store one value (below), but how do I do multiple values for the facebookID, userName, and userEmail?

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([defaults objectForKey:@"username"] == nil) //we haven't saved anything yet
    [defaults setObject:authenticatedUsersName forKey:@"username"];
```

Comment: You should probably be using the proper OAuth tokens instead... but lets see what answerers say.

Comment: You can't and shouldn't ask people for their log in information directly. Especially to store it somewhere else. The Facebook iOS SDK has single sign on now, or you can use the dialogs. This keeps everyones accounts protected from anyone trying to do what you want to do. The best you can do is save the images directly.

Comment: Totally disagree with the above comments. The Facebook graph exposes this information so that you can uniquely identify a user. OAuth tokens do not persist across multiple apps/devices.

Comment: I am working on storing it in NSUserDefaults.  Is that possible?  If so, how would you set multiple objects (setObject) forKey?  I have posted my current set up above in my edited question...

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with storing the Facebook User ID as the comments above suggest. The token can change between sessions and from device to device. Also if you have multiple apps (say web/android/iphone) you want the user to be recognized across devices. In fact, this is how you should uniquely reference a user.

Anyway, to get the fid do this:

On your fbDidLogin delegate method, add this line:

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];
```

Then setup the request delegate like so:

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {
    NSString *facebookId = [result objectForKey:@"id"];
    NSString *userName = [result objectForKey:@"name"];
    NSString *userEmail = [result objectForKey:@"email"]; 

    //do whatever you need to do with this info next 
    //(ie. save to db, pass to user singleton, whatever)

}
```

ps. the above code assumes you already have Facebook login implemented. I'm not going to post all that code since there is a step by step instruction for that part in their Getting Started documentation.

Comment: Thanks Joel. This is precisely what I needed. When you say his goes in the Request Delegate, I'm assuming you mean the FBRequest.m file? Or the Facebook.m file?  I am referring to the original names of the files that come with the FBook iOS SDK download.  Also, can you show me how I might append this information to the imagedata that I am already passing thru after the user hits "upload"?  I could post my current source code if you think you might be able to show me....

Comment: No, no, no. You have to implement the FBRequestDelegate in the same spot as you implemented FBLoginDialogDelegate. In your code. You probably implemented it on your application delegate. Once you are getting the facebookId correctly you should post a separate question for the MySQL part. I don't use MySQL so don't know it.

Comment: FBRequestDelegate is a protocol. So one of your classes should implement this protocol, so it can receive the delegate messages back from Facebook.

Comment: ps. If this answer works for you, please click the CHECKMARK to mark it as correct.

Comment: Ok, I will make sure I implement it in the right place.  Once I do that, is there any way to check to see if I am capturing the user ID correctly?  Outside of trying to implement the correct php pass-thru to MySQL?  I want to error check along the way so I can isolate where I am going wrong.

Comment: This is easy. Go to http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=XXXXXX and see if you land on the right page. Or use this method: http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=91532827198